# Should I split my (specific) post up into two questions after posting?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

This is pertaining to my recent question [What are the algebraic and geometric multiplicities of the eigenvalues of a Kronecker (or tensor) product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4682457/620957). I chose to ask about both the algebraic and geometric eigenvalues in the same question. It felt iffy, but I somehow thought that the answers would be both fairly short and closely related.

This doesn't seem to be the case after all, so I wonder if I should split it up now, sooner rather than later, before answers start coming in? I'm not sure how best to handle this. Since most comments have been about the algebraic multiplicity (which seems to be the easier case), I propose to edit the current post to be about algebraic multiplicity only, and then make a new post for the geometric multiplicity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, split it up.

This is evidently two distinct questions in the same post, which we (across Stack Exchange) want to avoid because it breaks the intended model and prevents the effective use of the systems available.

If they had turned out to be closely intertwined, then it would make sense to leave them together, but you already point out this is unlikely.

Also, even if it does turn out they're connected, there is no reason not to split them. A good answer will point out that such a connection exists; the questions themselves can be added to their respective *Related questions* lists; a third question could query how the two types are connected.

Comment: Thank you :) I was hesitant because changing the question after posting is also against guidelines (for good reason). I will split it up then, since I agree that this would be the better way to dig myself out of the hole I made

Comment: Definitely don't change the question when this invalidates answers, or when it changes the overall key points, but refining the question to a better form of what was present will usually be fine.